# Bootstrap 4 - full width form fields on inline form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, bootstrap-4

I've noticed a difference in how in-line forms behave between old Bootstrap v3 and new Bootstrap V4.

I have two code snippets:

### Bootstrap 3

In this version, when the page gets narrower, each form element resizes to take up the full width of the page. This no longer happens with Bootstrap 4. I can't see that the [Bootstrap 3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms) mentions this full-width behaviour though - but it still does it - as in, the fields still go to full-width on the inline form when they are in a `form-group` div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1>bootstrap/3.3.6</h1>

<form class='form-inline' role='form' action='search.php' method='post' id='form_search'>
   <input type='hidden' name='method' value='search' />
   <div class='form-group'>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' id='str' name='str' placeholder = 'Search'>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='mn' id='mn' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Month</option>
         <option  value='1'>January</option>
         <option  value='2'>February</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select class='form-control' name='yr' id='yr'>
         <option value='n'>Year</option>
         <option  value='1995'>1995</option>
         <option  value='1996'>1996</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='format' id='format' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Format</option>
         <option  value='1'>1</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='week_end_or_not' id='week_end_or_not' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Weekend Or Not</option>
         <option  value='week'>Week Days</option>
         <option  value='weekend'>Weekend</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='work_days' id='work_days' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Work Days?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='exact_phrase' id='exact_phrase' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Exact Phrase?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
</form>
```

### Bootstrap 4

Now when using the same HTML in Bootstrap 4, the full-width behaviour no longer happens. As with Bootstrap 3, I can't see any reference to the full-width form fields on narrower pages on inline forms in [the Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) though.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1>bootstrap/4.0.0</h1>

<form class='form-inline' role='form' action='search.php' method='post' id='form_search'>
   <input type='hidden' name='method' value='search' />
   <div class='form-group'>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' id='str' name='str' placeholder = 'Search'>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='mn' id='mn' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Month</option>
         <option  value='1'>January</option>
         <option  value='2'>February</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select class='form-control' name='yr' id='yr'>
         <option value='n'>Year</option>
         <option  value='1995'>1995</option>
         <option  value='1996'>1996</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='format' id='format' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Format</option>
         <option  value='1'>1</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='week_end_or_not' id='week_end_or_not' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Weekend Or Not</option>
         <option  value='week'>Week Days</option>
         <option  value='weekend'>Weekend</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='work_days' id='work_days' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Work Days?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <select name='exact_phrase' id='exact_phrase' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Exact Phrase?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
</form>
```

I wondered if anyone is aware of a way to replicate the behaviour in Bootstrap 4, so that the form-fields go full width in the same way they did in Bootstrap 3?

I don't want to remove the `class='form-inline'` from the form as I wanted to have the form display as inline on wider screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1: `.form-inline` without grouping

According to [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms), you can simply use the `.inline-form` class on your `<form>` element without grouping the single input elements (just remove the corresponding `<div class="form-group">` elements).

For adjusting breaking points, see the [*Responsive Breakpoints* section in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints).

Here is the working example (watch in fullscreen and change the viewport width to see the effect):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1>bootstrap/4.0.0</h1>

<form class='form-inline' role='form' action='search.php' method='post' id='form_search'>

  <input type='hidden' name='method' value='search' />

  <input type='text' class='form-control' id='str' name='str' placeholder='Search'>

  <select name='mn' id='mn' class='form-control'>
     <option value='n'>Month</option>
     <option  value='1'>January</option>
     <option  value='2'>February</option>
  </select>

  <select class='form-control' name='yr' id='yr'>
     <option value='n'>Year</option>
     <option  value='1995'>1995</option>
     <option  value='1996'>1996</option>
  </select>

  <select name='format' id='format' class='form-control'>
     <option value='n'>Format</option>
     <option  value='1'>1</option>
  </select>

  <select name='week_end_or_not' id='week_end_or_not' class='form-control'>
     <option value='n'>Weekend Or Not</option>
     <option  value='week'>Week Days</option>
     <option  value='weekend'>Weekend</option>
  </select>

  <select name='work_days' id='work_days' class='form-control'>
     <option value='n'>Work Days?</option>
     <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
     <option  value='no'>No</option>
  </select>

  <select name='exact_phrase' id='exact_phrase' class='form-control'>
     <option value='n'>Exact Phrase?</option>
     <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
     <option  value='no'>No</option>
  </select>

  <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>

</form>
```

## Solution 2: `.input-group` instead of `.form-group`

If you still want to group your input elements, you can change the `.form-group` elements to `.input-group` elements. See the section about *Multiple Inputs* in [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#multiple-inputs).

Here is the working example (watch in fullscreen and change the viewport width to see the effect):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1>bootstrap/4.0.0</h1>

<form class='form-inline' role='form' action='search.php' method='post' id='form_search'>
   <input type='hidden' name='method' value='search' />
   <div class='form-group'>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' id='str' name='str' placeholder = 'Search'>
   </div>
   <div class='input-group'>
      <select name='mn' id='mn' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Month</option>
         <option  value='1'>January</option>
         <option  value='2'>February</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='input-group'>
      <select class='form-control' name='yr' id='yr'>
         <option value='n'>Year</option>
         <option  value='1995'>1995</option>
         <option  value='1996'>1996</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='input-group'>
      <select name='format' id='format' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Format</option>
         <option  value='1'>1</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='input-group'>
      <select name='week_end_or_not' id='week_end_or_not' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Weekend Or Not</option>
         <option  value='week'>Week Days</option>
         <option  value='weekend'>Weekend</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='input-group'>
      <select name='work_days' id='work_days' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Work Days?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class='input-group'>
      <select name='exact_phrase' id='exact_phrase' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Exact Phrase?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @andreas that worked perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to put together such a useful reply.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove '.form-group' div from your code and you need to add media query for 767 resolution.
In Bootstrap 4 - input get 100% width below 576px wide screen.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .form-inline .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1>bootstrap/4.0.0</h1>

<form class='form-inline' role='form' action='search.php' method='post' id='form_search'>
   <input type='hidden' name='method' value='search' />
   
      <input type='text' class='form-control' id='str' name='str' placeholder = 'Search'>
   
      <select name='mn' id='mn' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Month</option>
         <option  value='1'>January</option>
         <option  value='2'>February</option>
      </select>
   
      <select class='form-control' name='yr' id='yr'>
         <option value='n'>Year</option>
         <option  value='1995'>1995</option>
         <option  value='1996'>1996</option>
      </select>
   
      <select name='format' id='format' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Format</option>
         <option  value='1'>1</option>
      </select>
   
      <select name='week_end_or_not' id='week_end_or_not' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Weekend Or Not</option>
         <option  value='week'>Week Days</option>
         <option  value='weekend'>Weekend</option>
      </select>
   
      <select name='work_days' id='work_days' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Work Days?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   
      <select name='exact_phrase' id='exact_phrase' class='form-control'>
         <option value='n'>Exact Phrase?</option>
         <option  value='yes'>Yes</option>
         <option  value='no'>No</option>
      </select>
   
   <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
</form>
```

Here is Fiddel [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7t2ufcne/5/)

Comment: Thanks @Minal Chauhan - I would have put this as the accepted answer, but andreas answered first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No Problem, First come First serve